# How to access property value in generic method in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

Imagine I have several classes of different types with the same property.

I want to make a generic method that should acess the value of the property of those classes.

The following code is invalid and will throw this error :

> Cannot resolve method 'GetValue(T)' (...)

.. so what's the proper way to do this?

```
public static List<int> FooBar<T>(T myObject)
{
  var myValue = typeof(T).GetProperty("myList").GetValue(myObject);

  return myValue;
}
```

Comment: That error message doesn't match the code you have shown here.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @DavidG I've updated the post following your notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "proper" way to do this is probably to have a `where T : SomeInterfaceOrBaseType`, i.e. the thing that *has* a `myList` member - and then just access it; i.e. `return myObject.myList;`

```cs
interface IFoo {
    List<int> myList {get;}
}
public static List<int> FooBar<T>(T myObject) where T : IFoo {
    return myObject.myList;
}
```

But... by the time you've done that, there's not really a need for the method any more, as if the caller knows that the type is an `IFoo`, they can do that themselves.

If you *must* do it via reflection... well, that's hard. It might be easier to just abuse `dynamic`:

```cs
public static List<int> FooBar<T>(T myObject)
{
    dynamic obj = myObject;
    List<int> myList = obj.myList;
    return myList;
}
```

Comment: Also, no point of using generics for this, you can simply take an `IFoo` as a parameter...

Comment: @ZoharPeled if the `T` could be a value-type, then the generic approach allows you to use "constrained call" rather than boxing, but... in general: I agree; of course, if we expect `T` to be a value-type, we might also speculate that it isn't trivially small, so it might also be good to add `in`, i.e. `in T myObject`

Comment: Yeah, it could, but that's an edge case and unless widely used, the boxing should have no noticeable effect on the overall performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this with generics, try the code below

```
 return (List<int>)(typeof(T).GetProperty("myList").GetValue(myObject, null))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this `myObject.GetType().GetProperty("myList").GetValue(myObject, null);`